# Existing database check vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I just want to simple check if there already is an existing record in my database. I get this error message:

> ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE voornaam= & txtfirstname.Text"
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Str)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader

con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\database test\ikeagoed\ikeagoed\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True"


con.Open()
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
dr.Read()

If txtfirstname.Text = dr("voornaam").ToString Then
    MsgBox("exist")
Else
    MsgBox("doesn't exist")
End If
con.Close()
```

Comment: Add connection to SqlCommand. e.g. Dim cmd as SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str,con)

Comment: Also note your query is invalid, as it's typed. You're probably missing an end quote after `voornaam=" & txtfirstname.Text`. Might want to do some reading about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you need to initialise the connection property on the `SqlCommand`.  You can either do so by modifying your call to the constructor:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Str, con) 'include connection parameter
```

or by setting the property after construction

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(Str)
cmd.Connection = con
```

That will get you past the first problem, but there are other issues with your code - the way you're assigning the textbox value into the sql command is not correct.  You need to do it as follows:

```
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE voornaam='" & txtfirstname.Text & "'"
```

But this then leads on the to the area of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Please be aware of what [it can cause](http://bobby-tables.com/) and ensure you guard against it - this area is too big for covering here in detail.

Answer (score 0):

simply just like this

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection

con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\database test\ikeagoed\ikeagoed\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

con.open()
Dim str As String
str = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE voornaam= & txtfirstname.Text"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Str,con)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


If dr.Read() Then

    MsgBox("exist")

Else

    MsgBox("doesn't exist")


End If
dr.close()
con.Close()
```